# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon') in Cordova

Tags: android, xml, cordova, apk

this is my .xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.example.hello" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
</manifest>
```

I've tried all the solution that I can get from stackoverflow, but still same problem appear when i build my apk. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Do you have an imagefile in `drawable` -> `icon.jpg or icon.png ?

Comment: yes, I create a new  cordova project and without add any coding to the index.html, I convert it, but I get this error without changing any origin file

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that "(at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon')",but what I can see is "android:icon="@mipmap/icon" "  from your code.

Comment: that what make me confused